# Which fonts are these?

Tags: font-identification

much obliged to any tips.  There are a few fonts here, mostly looking for the "Joy" one.

[image]

Comment: A quick search using Whatthefont.com came up with Francisco Serial Xbold, although this font does not include the detailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty good match for the "JOY" with [Imprint Shadow](http://www.identifont.com/show?3NN) on Identifont:

[image: Sample]

The "God's Joy is" text is almost certainly some variant of [Cheltenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheltenham_(typeface)).